# dvi mode - display other .dvi-file within .dvi-file

Tags: graphics, dvi-mode

Assume you have fileA.tex and compiling it via latex yields fileA.dvi.

What do you need to do if

- you **don't want to have fileA.dvi converted to some other format** (!!!)
- you wish to create a file fileB.tex which when compiling with latex yields fileB.dvi where within a rectangular square the content of fileA.dvi is displyed?

What do directives look like for importing one .dvi-file into another/for displaying one .dvi-file within another?

Comment: to display a dvi you have to convert it to another format.

Comment: I had written a utility dvitovf that converted a DVI file into a virtual font file that could be used to insert the DVI output of a TeX run as if it were a single character. Unfortunately, the code was lost a couple computers ago and I found that using pdftex and pdf inclusion was easier than reconstructing the program (which was actually a fairly simple program, it turned out).

Comment: @JennaDenna  What exactly are you trying to achieve? Image-inclusion in .dvi-format does not incorporate the image (be the image itself a .dvi-file or whatever) itself into the .dvi-file. Within the .dvi-file the area for displaying the image is reserved and you find some directives for .dvi-viewers to display the **external(!)** image-file in question within that area. Whether a viewer or a program for converting from dvi to pdf understands that directive is another question.

Comment: see the dvipaste  command (I have not used it this millennium but it used to work...)

Comment: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/dviware/dvipaste and latex package wrapper https://ctan.org/pkg/grfpaste

Answer (score 2):

The `grfpaste` package (which is in texlive) allows you to use `\includegraphics{file.dvi}` to include a referenced dvi file as you describe.

It requires the `grfpaste` program (which I have not run for some decades, but should still work) it is no longer distributed with texlive but the sources are on ctan at https://ctan.org/pkg/dvipaste

Comment: Seems the sources don't compile nowadays.  You encounter a nice mess of messages like ````config.h:1:13: error: both 'long' and 'short' in declaration specifiers```` or ````dvipaste.c:346:6: warning: implicit declaration of function 'exit' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  exit(1);  ^~~~````

Comment: @UlrichDiez it compiled for me This is DVIPASTE, Version 1.21
Copyright (c) 1989-91, The TeXplorators Corporation.
All rights reserved.  I had to fiddle with `config.h` a bit

Comment: @UlrichDiez oh I didn't think of reading my own documentation:-) I just came up with teh same #define as I suggested there!

Comment: @UlrichDiez instead of `#define stricmp`  you'd need to includ eci.c something like changing the makefile to dvipaste: dvipaste.o ci.o 
 cc -o dvipaste co.o dvipaste.o

dvipaste.o: ci.c dvipaste.c config.h

Comment: @UlrichDiez since the ctan catalogue claims that I maintain grfpaste I may look later to see if I can get it to compile cleanly and post something here.

Comment: Seems I got it to compile cleanly for debian buster. I raised an [issue at GitHub](https://github.com/davidcarlisle/dpctex/issues/29#issue-800700948) for elaborating the details. But it seems the dvipaste-program doesn't like dvi-files created with LaTeX, using nowadays' `dvips.def`/`l3backend-dvips.def`.